# Percentage shows 10000% instead of 100% in Power BI. How to fix this?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have been trying to get Power BI to show me the actual value of a percentage which is 100% or anything below than that for my report but what it rather does is it displays 10000% instead of 100%.

How can I sort it out? I have attached a screenshot for your convenience.
Files used : Microsoft Excel

[image: powerbi]

Comment: Like Excel, when formatting a percentage, it treats the input as a decimal number between 0 and 1, where 0 means 0% and 1 means 100%. Then 100 *would* mean 10000%. So if your inputs are in the range 0-100, just divide them by 100 before asking PBI to show them as a %.

Comment: @underscore_d thanks for your respond. Can I divide them by 100 in Power BI itself?

Comment: In the Query Editor, select the column and go to Transform tab > Number Column section > Standard > Divide and divide by 100.

Comment: @AlexisOlson Thanks. It did fix the issue but when I am creating a dashboard with a Clustered bar chart, it shows the maximum percentage of 200%.

Comment: So open another question about your new problem. To close off this question, @AlexisOlson may or may not want to post an answer; if they don't, you can post your own and accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @underscore_d points out, percentages between 0% and 100% correspond to numeric values between 0 and 1. So, if your data is in the range of 0 to 100, this corresponds to 0% to 10000%.

To fix this, you can divide the column by 100 in the query editor. To do this, select the column and go to Transform tab > Number Column section > Standard > Divide and divide by 100.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: This creates a new column. Can I simply divide the new column by 100 in place (I know I could just remove my original column and rename my new column to the old name if I wanted).

Comment: @SteveIves use the Transform tab rather than the Add column tab

Comment: Thanks - still fairly new at this and not really used to the way it works.